# Два разных navbar'a

Tags: html, bootstrap

Знатоки, внимание вопрос!) 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу сделать два разных навбара через бутстрап, чтобы у них были разные свойства? Можно ли так вообще?

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="demo.html">Демо-доступ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Это мой основной navbar.
Мне нужно под ним сделать navbar меньших размеров, смещенный по центру.
Подскажите плиз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задаете своему меню дополнительный класс (`class="my-navigation"`) + не забывайте про свой `id` для `navbar-collapse` (соответственно и такой же для `<button ...  data-target="...">` ...).

Добавляете свои стили для данного меню `.my-navigation { ... }`.

Выравнивание, как правило, делают с помощью bootstrap grid, например:

```
.container
  .row
     .col-md-10
```

Выбирайте любое:

```css
.navbar-2 {
  background: #333;
}

.navbar-2.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-2.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-3 {
  background: tomato;
}

.navbar-3 .navbar-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-3 .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-3 .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-3 .nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-3 .nav > li > a:focus {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--   Основное меню -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="demo.html">Демо-доступ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Меню 2 c классом navbar-2-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-2">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse2">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse2">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="demo.html">Демо-доступ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Меню 3 c классом navbar-3-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
      <div class="navbar navbar-3">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse3">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse3">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="index.html">Главная</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="demo.html">Демо-доступ</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="catalog.html">Каталог</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="contact.html">Контакты</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**P.S:** Больше ознакомьтесь с возможностями bootstrap!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете свободно размещать столько навбаров на странице, сколько вам требуется. "Смещенный по центру навбар меньших размеров" можно создать так:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
  Верхний навбар из вашего примера
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    Навбар ниже. Смещен по центру за счет вписывания в .container
  </div>
</div>
```

Если хотите навбар по-другому оформить стилистически - можете воспользоваться бутстраповскими классами для навбаров разных цветов - `.navbar-default` и `.navbar-inverse`. Либо создать свой класс вида `.navbar-xxx`, стилизовать его, как вам хочется, и использовать вместо `.navbar-default`.